# Selecting div in li element and do action on li-click

Tags: jquery, events, dom, select

I think I have an issue with selecting. Actually I have a div conataining two other divs of thes same size (front and back). I want to create an on-click event so that it's like having two sides of a card. No flip effect needed only covering/revealing on click.

My html relevant for this:

```
enter code here`enter code here`<ul id="boxes">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="rotate">
<div class="flip-container">
<div class="front">
<img src="kuh.jpg">
</div>  
<div class="back">
<p>Oohh...behave!"Austin Powers"</p>
</div>
</div>      
</ul>

enter code here$(function() {
```

This would be the jQuery. adding Class "goaway" sets the respective element on z-index -2 which reveals the div behind. I tried it setting it up in CSS.

```
$("#boxes li").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).next(".front").hasClass("goaway")){
        $(this).next(".front").removeClass("goaway");
    }else{
        $(this).next(".front").addClass("goaway");  
    }
});
```

Thanks for any useful links. I am sure this is the right direction but can't figure out why it wouldn't work.

BR

**New JS with fadeToggle, delay and clearQueue and stop.**

```
$(function() {$("#boxes li").on("click", 
function(){$(this).find(".front,.back").clearQueue().stop().fadeToggle(800)
.delay(10000).fadeToggle(800);});});
```

When clicking more often on the li it would abord the function as expected but then after 10 seconds delay switch to the back. I thought that it would abord each step and therefore should show the front side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working demo with required CSS to show it works properly http://jsfiddle.net/VRu6X/1/

Small amount of jQuery required

```
$("#boxes li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('.front,.back').toggleClass('goaway');
});
```

HTML, needs back to start with having class goaway

```
<ul id="boxes">
    <li class="rotate">
        <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="front">
                FRONT
           </div>  
            <div class="back goaway">
                BACK
            </div>
        </div>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

*"One more thing, as the transition is quite rough I was looking for an option to switch classes more smoothly. could I apply some fading on your solution"*

You can show and hide more smoothly 

Set back to not show

```
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="front">
            FRONT
       </div>  
       <div class="back" style="display:none">
            BACK
       </div>
    </div>
```

and use `fadeToggle()` http://jsfiddle.net/VRu6X/2/ 
or `slideToggle()` perhaps http://jsfiddle.net/VRu6X/3/

```
$("#boxes li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('.front,.back').fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

**Alternatively**, you could flip the card http://jsfiddle.net/VRu6X/5/

```
<ul id="boxes">
    <li class="rotate">
        <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="front">
                <img src="http://www.madore.org/~david/images/cards/english/king-clubs.png" />
           </div>  
           <div class="back" style="display:none;">
                <img src="http://chetart.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/playing-card-back.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#boxes li{
    display:block;
}
.flip-container{
    position:relative;
}
.flip-container div{
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:130px;
}

.front img, .back img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

JS

```
$("#boxes li").on("click", function(){
    //$(this).find('.front,.back').slideToggle(500);
    var $showing=$(this).find('.front:visible, .back:visible');
    var $notshowing=$(this).find('.front:not(:visible), .back:not(:visible)')
    $showing.animate({height:0, marginTop:100}, 300, function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $notshowing.show().css({height:0, marginTop:100}).animate({height:200, marginTop:0}, 300);
    });
});
```

Please note the height and margins in the jQuery are set rather than being looked up, so if you change the CSS you'll have to change that to, or do it the right way (letting jQuery discover the height the first time)

Comment: Thank you, that worked just fine. Can you also tell me why my code did not work? For me it just looked fine and was quite logic. Thanks in advance

Comment: One more thing, as the transition is quite rough I was looking for an option to switch classes more smoothly. could I apply some fading on your solution without UI? What I tried is to simply set "slow" in toggleClass but it wouldn't work! THX

Comment: OK .... as your fiddle prooves it works, I believe you though I could not set it up in my code in the first run. I will tweak around a bit... This was exactly what I was looking for. Last thing as I am eager to learn: what was wrong with my initial code?

Comment: Edit: it works just fine. Only thing left, but most interesting, is knowledge transfer on why my code did not work. Thx

Comment: `$(this).next(".front")` look in the jQuery docs to see what `.next()` does. It does not `.find()`

Comment: Hi popnoodles, u r right: .next() wasn't the best selection. Just looked it up and next would select the next sibling. And in my code there wasn't a sigling with the class .front therefore it did nothing. I have one question left regarding improvement. which jQuery element would stop the ongoing fadeToggle as I added another function .delay. I wanted that the it toggles back after say 10 seconds wich works fine. Only problem is that if people mess with clicking it ends up in a mess. My guess was clearQueue().stop(). Altough this worked fine, after 10 seconds delay it switched to the back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the z-index?

`.comehere { z-index: 2; }`

```
$(document).on('click', '.flip-container', function() {
    $(this).child('.front').toggleClass('comehere').toggleClass('goaway');
}
```

Comment: Since you're taking cues from my answer anyway `.toggleClass('comehere goaway')`

Comment: Didn't notice you do it until I'd finished editing, but yeah.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. This approach however, did not work. Therefore I sticked to the first answer by @popnoodles which was just fine. Regards